# Regarding overriding Principles

Tags: java

I was developing a program keeping the concept of overriding in my mind..

```
class Parent
{
    private void method1 () {
        System.out.println ("Parent's method1 ()");
    }
    public void method2 () {
        System.out.println ("Parent's method2 ()");
            method1 ();
    }
}

class Child extends Parent
{
    public void method1 ()  {
        System.out.println ("Child's method1 ()");
    }
       //overriding
    public void method2 ()  {
        System.out.println ("Child's method2 ()");
    }

    public static void main (String args []) {
        Parent p = new Child ();
        p.method2 ();//parent
    }
}
```

Now when I call the method2() , parent class method2() is called  , as seen above I am passing the parent reference while creating the object but in similar fashion if I want to access child class method2(), then one approach is to directly make the object of child class but If I want to call child class method2() in similar fashion by passing the parent reference then how it would be possible please advise.

Comment: I don't understand your question at all. The child class doesn't have a method2. I don't see how it could ever be called.

Comment: @JBNizet Child class does have a method2, it inherits it from Parent.

Comment: Now that you have edited your question, try running the code. The Child's method2 method will be invoked., because the object is of type Child.

Comment: @JBNizet so it is dynamic binding , decision is taken on object type..!!

Comment: There is no child class method2().  You haven't defined one.

Comment: Yes, methods are called polymorphically in Java.

Comment: See the output here, p.Method2 is polymorphic, it invokes the Child's overriding function rather than the parent's function http://ideone.com/Z9Kr0

Comment: This is a good puzzle on achieving polymorphism on overloaded method. I'm also studying Java now, I'm thinking of how to achieve this in Java :-) http://www.ienablemuch.com/2012/04/multiple-dispatch-in-c.html

Comment: Can't resist it. I noticed that there's a bit of recursion and pun that can be made out this question's title. **The overriding principles of Java is one of the overriding principles of Java**

Answer (score -1):

Srinivas Reddy Thatiparthy answered the previous version of your question.

If you override a method in a child class, then any child instance will use the child class method.

You can execute the parent method from the child method by including a `super.method2()` method invocation in your child method.

Or, you can cast the child to a parent object, and then invoke the method.:

```
Parent parent = (Parent) child;
parent.method2();
```

Comment: The last part is completely wrong, and shows that you haven't understood what polymorphism and casting are. Casting a child to a parent won't change anything. A child is a child and will always be a child. The fact that you reference it as a parent doesn't change its child nature.

Comment: Parent p = new Child(); //child method2()n is being called 
p.method2();//parent  , I am still getting of method2() of parent